# when I try to format my hard disk ubuntu live show me - no media - my hard disk?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04

I am trying to format my hard disk using an **Ubuntu live** inside an USB but my Ubuntu live does not recognize my hard disk and it showed me: `No Media`.

How could I fix it ?

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What brand/model system? Was drive partitioned & formatted before? If Windows fast startup or bitlocker on that can prevent mount of a drive. Or some systems need drive changed from RAID to AHCI. But if dual booting with Windows you have to install AHCI drivers to WIndows for it to work. If newer system be sure to gpt partition & UEFI boot.

Comment: Usually you format a partition, not a full disk.  Maybe your hard disk is totally blank, without even a partition table. Run a partitioning tool like gdisk or gparted, put a gpt partition table on it, add a partition of type ext4,and if your partition tool does not run mkfs for you, add a filesystem.

Comment: how can i do it that ? sorry I am new using ubuntu

Comment: Please add requested information to your original posting. Particularly confirm that there is nothing on the disk before we start adding partition tables and partitions, since that will destroy whatever is already on the disk -- note 3000+ bad sectors on the disk is not a good sign. Attract the attention of the comment posters with a comment/question including the @ sign before their username.